# Update table in remote offline database in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I know this is a  bit silly one, but I have a question on how to update an offline database.

I have various databases in the same folder (they are all offline and redistributable - being an analytic tool to be used with csv and txt files produced by SAP.) It is crucial for the company for this tool to be offline and operated by VBA for Access + SQL. I am trying to bypass the 2GB limit by employing various databases. One of them is a central database where I have forms and run the code. I have various join queries and that create new tables that are used for reports etc.

How can I join two tables (existing ones) in a remote offline database (existing one) and insert it into a new table (not existing) in a database (existing one)?

```
Sub adddatesALT()
Dim sDate As String
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Dim ssql as String
```

dbinput is database called UNION  with tables AGR_USERS_ALL, USR_02_ALL and  that's where the tables are (FROM)

dboutput is the database called MASTER and that's where I want to insert the tables (IN)

```
dbinput = "[" & Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\UNION.accdb" & "]"
dboutput = "[" & Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\MASTER.accdb" & "]"
```

Short one - how to incorporate the path into an update query?

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("UPDATE AGR_USERS_ALL SET AGR_USERS_ALL.JNC_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' WHERE ((AGR_USERS_ALL.TO_DAT) > (AGR_USERS_ALL.CH_DATE));")
```

And the major one - how to incorporate it the path into a more complex query as this one

```
ssql = "SELECT AGR_USERS_ALL.AGR_NAME, AGR_USERS_ALL.UNAME, AGR_USERS_ALL.FROM_DAT, AGR_USERS_ALL.TO_DAT, AGR_USERS_ALL.COL_FLAG, AGR_USERS_ALL.JNC_STATUS, USR_02_ALL.JNC_STATUS, USR_02_ALL.USTYP, USR_06_ALL.LIC_TYPE INTO USR02_AGR_ACTIVE_ROLES"
ssql = ssql & " FROM (AGR_USERS_ALL INNER JOIN USR_02_ALL ON (AGR_USERS_ALL.UNAME = USR_02_ALL.BNAME) AND (AGR_USERS_ALL.[SYSTEM NO] = USR_02_ALL.[SYSTEM NO])) INNER JOIN USR_06_ALL ON (USR_02_ALL.BNAME = USR_06_ALL.BNAME) AND (USR_02_ALL.[SYSTEM NO] = USR_06_ALL.[SYSTEM NO])"
ssql = ssql & " WHERE (((AGR_USERS_ALL.COL_FLAG) Is Null) AND ((AGR_USERS_ALL.JNC_STATUS)<>'Expired') AND ((USR_02_ALL.JNC_STATUS)<>'Expired') AND ((USR_02_ALL.USTYP)<>'B' And (USR_02_ALL.USTYP)<>'L'));"
DoCmd.RunSQL ssql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much!

I found a solution in the meantime, but I will also follow your advice ;)

My solution is:

```
Sub USR02AGRJOIN()
Dim ssql As String
Dim ssql2 As String
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Dim dbinput As String
Dim dboutput As String

dboutput = "[" & Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\MASTER.accdb" & "]"
dbinput = "'" & Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\UNION.accdb" & "'"

ssql = "SELECT AGR_USERS_ALL.AGR_NAME, AGR_USERS_ALL.UNAME, AGR_USERS_ALL.FROM_DAT, AGR_USERS_ALL.TO_DAT, AGR_USERS_ALL.COL_FLAG, AGR_USERS_ALL.JNC_STATUS, USR_02_ALL.JNC_STATUS, USR_02_ALL.USTYP, USR_06_ALL.LIC_TYPE INTO " & dboutput & ".USR02_AGR_ACTIVE_ROLES"
ssql = ssql & " FROM (AGR_USERS_ALL INNER JOIN USR_02_ALL ON (AGR_USERS_ALL.UNAME = USR_02_ALL.BNAME) AND (AGR_USERS_ALL.[SYSTEM NO] = USR_02_ALL.[SYSTEM NO])) INNER JOIN USR_06_ALL ON (USR_02_ALL.BNAME = USR_06_ALL.BNAME) AND (USR_02_ALL.[SYSTEM NO] = USR_06_ALL.[SYSTEM NO]) IN " & dbinput & ""
ssql = ssql & " WHERE (((AGR_USERS_ALL.COL_FLAG) Is Null) AND ((AGR_USERS_ALL.JNC_STATUS)<>'Expired') AND ((USR_02_ALL.JNC_STATUS)<>'Expired') AND ((USR_02_ALL.USTYP)<>'B' And (USR_02_ALL.USTYP)<>'L'));"
DoCmd.RunSQL ssql

End Sub
```

I have just struggled with syntax :)

Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways to do this

---

1. Use the [IN Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-12/bb177907(v=office.12))

For the short one that gives

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("UPDATE AGR_USERS_ALL IN '" & dboutput  & "' SET AGR_USERS_ALL.JNC_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' WHERE ((AGR_USERS_ALL.TO_DAT) > (AGR_USERS_ALL.CH_DATE));")
```

---

2. [Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-link-to-data-in-another-access-database-095ab408-89c7-45b3-aac2-58036e45fcf6?ocmsassetID=HA001227658&CorrelationId=364a1514-c501-4763-be39-d8fa2360e7b5&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#BM3) the external tables.

This is for me the best solution. Linked tables are one of the strengths of Access, and your queries will stay simple.

To do it efficiently, prefix the linked table name with its database name so you always know from which DB is a table

For the short one that gives

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("UPDATE MASTER_AGR_USERS_ALL SET MASTER_AGR_USERS_ALL.JNC_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' WHERE ((MASTER_AGR_USERS_ALL.TO_DAT) > (MASTER_AGR_USERS_ALL.CH_DATE));")
```

---

Use exactly the same tricks for the "major one". It doesn't matter wether its an UPDATE or SELECT statement, or if its a big or short query.